# $\pm$ in solving differential equations by separation of variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I know how to do separation of variables with differential equations, like $\frac{dy\left(x\right)}{dx}=4y\left(x\right)$ when $y\left(0\right)=4$ will get me $y=4e^{4x}$ in the end.

But when I'm solving for y, once I get to the stage where $\left|y\left(x\right)\right|=e^{4x} e^{C_1}$, do I replace as $C=\pm e^{C_1}$ or is that $\pm$ unnecessary?

Generally, it seems unnecessary since $e^x$ is always positive but couldn't it be the case that, if I had $y\left(0\right)=-4$, then I'd need to have that negative sign to get $y=-4e^{4x}$

Comment: It's simply $y=ce^{4x}$

Comment: Yes, but what is $C$ in this case? Would you need to state $\pm$?

Comment: C  can be anything a positive number or a negative one.. So the solution is $ce^{4x}$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Thanks for the answer since that's the heart of my question. Normally, I think you'd just write down $C$, with the understanding that it could be anything (like in your answer). But if we wanted to define $C$ when we substitute it with $e^{C_1}$, wouldn't we need to have the $\pm$ since the exponential is always positive?

Comment: Yes with the exponential since it is always positive but in all textbook the final answer will be rewritten with a simple constant $ C \in \mathbb{R}$. Even though $\pm e^c$ is also correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$y'=4y$$
With integrating factor method:
$$y'-4y=0$$
$$(ye^{-4x})'=0$$
$$ye^{-4x}=C$$
$$y(x)=Ce^{4x}$$
With $C \in \mathbb{R}$. You don't really need the $\pm $.